# How to read / accept / reject meeting invite in Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

When someone sends me a meeting invite from Microsoft Outlook, I don't get a properly formatted e-mail in my Mozilla Thunderbird. I cannot accept nor reject the meeting invite.

Can anyone please let me know how to view / accept / reject meeting invites in Thunderbird?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but it's too old to migrate, sadly. It did help me, though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Lightning add-on](https://web.archive.org/web/20180715102145/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/) for thunderbird. After installing and restarting you can now accept outlook invitations

[image: lightning]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/18/18247.png?modified=1331247702))</sub>

Comment: Could you please post steps / links from where I can download the Lightining add-on?

Comment: It's been a long time since the last time I used thunderbird so I don't know if the UI has changed much or not. But you can always open the menu, select add-ons and search for lightning. You can reference [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_6471743_receive-outlook-invitations-thunderbird.html) although I think it's bit old

Comment: I now see Accept / Decline buttons for meeting invites, but have not found any way to view the date and time before clicking Accept. Outlook is sending the invitations base64 encoded so I can't easily see the plaintext either.